# JSON Simple - Encoding Array

Tags: java, json, json-simple

Hi I am using JSON simple library.
I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
    "string",
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
]
```

I have no problem parsing it. But when I finish my application and try to save the changes I cannot add a string to new JSONArray.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add("string");
```

It gives me `add(E) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)` error.
There is no `put` method in the JSONArray class.
The solution might be converting JSONObject to JSONArray. But how?

Or could I parse the file and change the contects and then overwrite the original file with it?

Look at the Example 2-1
https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/wikis/EncodingExamples.wiki

**EDIT:** Using the code below always gives an error. I believe JSONArray object is not intented for encoding. I used a LinkedList instead.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add("string"); // gives error
array.add(obj); // gives error
```

Comment: You should use jsonObj instead of String objects check this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963751/json-add-to-jsonarray-issue).

Comment: @NAIT No, still same problem. add function doesn't work.

Comment: can you post what you tried please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); 
list.add("foo"); 
list.add(new Integer(100)); 
list.add(new Double(1000.21)); 
list.add(new Boolean(true)); 
list.add(null); 
String jsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(list); 
System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Instead of creating an `JSONArray` object and adding other objects to it, we can create a `LinkedList`.

Then use it as we intent to use a `JSONArray` object. And finally we can convert it to JSON string.

Problem might be as the error text suggest, JSONArray which extends ArrayList don't have a template set. It is still default `E`. So when you try to add an object to ArrayList, it gives an error because the object is not an instance of `E`. And JSONArray class doesn't accept template.

```
JSONArray<String> array = new JSONArray<String>();
```

Just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may add Json object instead of adding string object.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\""string",\":\"{}\"}");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct JSONArray. The example you posted uses

import org.json.**simple**.JSONArray;

Comment: That was the first thing I checked.