# Put JSONObjet into JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a problem putting JSONObject into JSONArray.

Here is my code:

```
String strObject = "{\"Code\":\"a\", \"Name\": \"b\"}";
JSONObject anExistedObject = new JSONObject(strObject);
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();

for(int count = 0; count < 2; count++){
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject;
    myObject = anExistedObject;

    myObject.put("Count", count);
    myArray.put(myObject);
}

System.out.println(myArray.toString());
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Code": "a",
        "Name": "b",
        "Count": 1
    },
    {
        "Code": "a",
        "Name": "b",
        "Count": 1
    }
]
```

What I expected:

```
[
    {
        "Code": "a",
        "Name": "b",
        "Count": 0
    },
    {
        "Code": "a",
        "Name": "b",
        "Count": 1
    }
]
```

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963751/json-add-to-jsonarray-issue) but still don't know how to fix mine.
Did I missed something?

Comment: Your code is incorrect, please post the actual code which produced this output. Otherwise we can't help you solve this specific issue

Comment: You each time modify same object because of line: `myObject = anExistedObj;`

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I've edited. My mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @DawidDrozd Yes. This line is my problem and I still don't know how to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating and reusing anExistedObject everytime

```
String strObject = "{\"Code\":\"a\", \"Name\": \"b\"}";
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();

for(int count = 0; count < 2; count++){
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(strObject);

    myObject.put("Count", count);
    myArray.put(myObject);
}

System.out.println(myArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You each time modify same object because of line: `myObject = anExistedObj;`
You need make copy of that object instead.

Correct code:

```
JSONObject anExistedObj = new JSONObject();
myObject.put("Code", "a");
myObject.put("Name", "a");

JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(anExistedObj);

for(int count = 0; count < 2; count++){
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(anExistedObj, keys);
    //anExistedObj = {"Code":"a", "Name": "b"}

    myObject.put("Count", count);
    myArray.put(myObject);
}

System.out.println(myArray.toString());
```

Checkout documentation of [copy constructor JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf240/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-oracle.adfmf.json.JSONObject-java.lang.String:A-)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the line `myObject.put("Count", count);` always modifies the same object since the variable is only a *reference* to the object itself. Meaning that `myObject` and `anExistedObject` point to the same object.

You should create a copy with:

```
JSONObject copy = new JSONObject(original, JSONObject.getNames(original));
```

Instead of using:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject;
myObject = anExistedObj;
```