# Handler Error: When inserting JSONObject in a JSONArray (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, json, api

I have the following JSON Data, with hits having multiple recipe objects

`"hits": [
{
"recipe": {
"uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_b79327d05b8e5b838ad6cfd9576b30b6",
"label": "Chicken Vesuvio",
"image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e42/e42f9119813e890af34c259785ae1cfb.jpg",
"source": "Serious Eats",
"url": "http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/12/chicken-vesuvio-recipe.html",
"shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/chicken-vesuvio-b79327d05b8e5b838ad6cfd9576b30b6/chicken",
"yield": 4,`

However, I'm trying to get all the recipe objects which are children elements of hits
Using this code

```
JSONArray recipeArray = null;

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);  //initial JSONObject (See explanation section below)

            JSONArray results = (JSONArray) json.get("hits");

            for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){

                JSONObject resultObject = (JSONObject) results.get(i);
                JSONObject recipeobj = (JSONObject) resultObject.get("recipe");
                recipeArray.put(recipeobj);
            }
```

During runtime,  recipeArray.put gives a handler exception. 
I have tried several methods on trying to do this such as looping the following

```
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);  
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("hits");  
            JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); JSONArray
            JSONArray recipeArray = item.getJSONArray("recipe");
```

But gives a conversion error during the last line.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you can refer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963751/json-add-to-jsonarray-issue

Comment: @Raushan That is not the issue, i did try it and it did not work. Thank you for your help tho :)

Answer (score 0):

As your inner `recipe` object is not an array, it will throw `JSONException` for this

```
JSONArray recipeArray = item.getJSONArray("recipe");
```

And in your initial approach, `recipeArray` is not initialized which would have caused you NPE.

you can do like this

```
JSONArray recipes = new JSONArray();

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){
  JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONObject recipe = item.getJSONObject("recipe");

  recipes.put(recipe);
}
```